# Java regex dies on stack overflow: need a better version

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a [JMD (Java MarkDown)](http://github.com/cletus/jmd) (a Java port of [MarkDownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/)) but I'm having an issue with one regex in particular. For the file [Markdown_Documentation_Syntax.text](http://github.com/cletus/jmd/blob/master/src/test/resources/functionality/Markdown_Documentation_Syntax.text) this regular expression dies:

```
private static final String BLOCK_TAGS_1 = "p|div|h[1-6]|blockquote|pre|table|dl|ol|ul|script|noscript|form|fieldset|iframe|math|ins|del";
private static final String BLOCKS_NESTED_PATTERN = String.format("" +
        "(" +                      // save in $1
        "^" +                      // start of line (with MULTILINE)
        "<(%s)" +                  // start tag = $2
        "\\b" +                    // word break
        "(.*\\n)*?" +              // any number of lines, minimally matching
        "</\\2>" +                 // the matching end tag
        "[ \\t]*" +                // trailing spaces/tags
        "(?=\\n+|\\Z)" +           // followed by a newline or end of
        ")", BLOCK_TAGS_1);
```

which translates to:

```
(^<(p|div|h[1-6]|blockquote|pre|table|dl|ol|ul|script|noscript|form|fieldset|iframe|math|ins|del)\b(.*\n)*?</\2>[ \t]*(?=\n+|\Z))
```

This pattern is looking for accepted block tags that are anchored to the start of a line, followed by any number of lines and then are terminated by a matching tag followed by a newline or a string terminator. This generates:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$LazyLoop.match(Pattern.java:4357)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3366)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$LazyLoop.match(Pattern.java:4357)
        ...
```

This can be dealt with by increasing the stack space for Java (defaults to 128k/400k for oss/ss IIRC) but the above expression is slow anyway.

So I'm looking for a regex guru who can do better (or at least explain the performance problem with this pattern). The C# version is a little slow but works fine. PHP seems to have no issues with this either.

**Edit:** This is on JDK6u17 running on Windows 7 64 Ultimate.

Comment: This is an awful use of regular expressions.  Do you have to use regexes or can you recast this as a real recursive parser (either LR or recursive descent)?

Comment: Have you tried with `.*\n` to `.*?\n`?

Comment: @S.Mark: the pattern is MULTILINE but not DOTALL so the backtracking involved I believe should be minimal but I'll try it.

Comment: @Jim: my first goal is to get a functionally equivalent version of the code with broad unit test coverage. The regexes come from MarkdownSharp (and before then, probably from the original Perl Markdown scripts). One step at a time.

Comment: @cletus, I see, if pattern is MULTILINE should be ok, I thought the problem was in `\\2` and I thought it was that group `(.*\n)`.

Comment: <Insert obligatory jwz quote here>

Comment: Wow, I can't believe someone bothers to quote a 9 year old rant, most of which isn't even relevant anymore.

Comment: @cletus: It looks like your test classes aren't included in your jmd-0.8.0-sources.jar download.  Any plans on adding them?

Comment: @Bill: I've uploaded a test jar.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This part:

```
(.*\n)*?
```

will involve A LOT of unnecessary backtracking because of the nested `*` and since there are chars that have to match afterwards.

I just ran a quick benchmark in perl on some arbitrary strings and got a 13-15% improvement just by switching that piece to

```
(?>.*\n)*?
```

which does non-capturing, independent subgrouping. That gives you two benefits, it no longer wastes time capturing the matching string, and more importantly, it no longer backtracks on the innermost `.*` which is a waste of time anyway.  There's no way that only a portion of that .* will ever result in a valid match so explicitly making it all or nothing should help.

Don't know if that's a sufficient improvement in this case, however.

Comment: Had a even more complex regex but the `?>` to ignore capturing solved the issue! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

While improving the pattern does help and is advisable, Java's pattern matcher is recursive and it is generally best to switch to an iterative solution.

When I had similar problems, I switched to jregex ([http://jregex.sourceforge.net/](http://jregex.sourceforge.net/.)) and that worked for me.

The pattern match may have succeeded now with the improved solution, but it may fail if a text 10 times as big was given.

PS: Sorry for necromancing an old topic but this thread is ranked highly on google and it would benefit people if I put it here

Answer (score 0):

The sub-expression: `"(.*\\n)*?"` (and the improved accepted answer version: `"(?>.*\n)*?"`), both have a problem: They fail to match a block element written on one line. In other words, they fail to match this:

```
<div>one-liner</div>
```

If this is not the desired behavior, a correct (and much more efficient) solution is to simply use:

`.*?`

And turn on single line mode.